# How to set a variable in powershell then get variable from cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm executing a powershell script from cmd window. Within the powershell script I want to set a variable that later can be reached from cmd window, once the ps script has finsihed.
How do I do that?

I have tried:
PS promt: Set-Variable -Name "MyParameter" -Value "MyParameter1234" -Scope Global -Visibility Public
CMD promt: set MyParameter

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: probably easiest way is to write to disk and read it from there

Comment: You can't change the environment of your parent process. You could start PS with a batchfile that calls a batchfile generated by PS to set it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to write the variable to a file, close the Powershell window, read the file in the cmd window and put it in to a variable and then delete the file.

Comment: Yes I have thought about that and I have tried it but it seems a little bit like stone age, but then again it works:)
Thanks for your reply!